# AngularJS and ng-class

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, ng-class

I have the next html code:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse menu-sidebar">
    <ul class="nav nav-stacked" id="menu-bar">
        <li class="panel dropdown" ng-repeat="m in menuSidebar.links">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#menu-bar" data-target="#{{'menuSidebar' + $index}}" href="">
                {{m.text}}
            </a>
            <div id="{{'menuSidebar' + $index}}" class="panel-collapse collapse submenu-sidebar">
                <ul class="nav nav-stacked">
                    <li ng-repeat="s in m.sub" ng-class="{active: s.active}"><a href="{{s.link}}">{{s.text}}</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the next json:

```
$scope.menuSidebar = {
    "links": [
        {
            "text": "Total",
            "sub": [
                {
                    "active": true,
                    "link": "#",
                    "text": "General"
                },
                {
                    "active": false,
                    "link": "#",
                    "text": "Cargos"
                },
                {
                    "active": false,
                    "link": "#",
                    "text": "Prestadora"
                },
                {
                    "active": false,
                    "link": "#",
                    "text": "Factura"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "text": "Departamento",
            "sub": [
                {
                    "active": false,
                    "link": "#",
                    "text": "Costos"
                },
                {
                    "active": false,
                    "link": "#",
                    "text": "Tiempos"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

I would like to define the class of the div in the case that any of the child is `active==true`.

```
<div id="{{'menuSidebar' + $index}}" ng-class="active: ..." class="panel-collapse collapse submenu-sidebar">
```

How to loop through all the children and determine the class? It is possible use ng-class in this case?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

no need to parse all the children define a "some_active" variable in your controller by doing

```
<li ng-repeat="s in m.sub" ng-class="{active: s.active}" ng-init="$parent.some_active=$parent.some_active||s.active"><a href="{{s.link}}">{{s.text}}</a></li>
```

then you can use

```
<div id="{{'menuSidebar' + $index}}" ng-class="{active:some_active}" class="panel-collapse collapse submenu-sidebar">
```

this solution requires that you also modify some_active variable on the on click handlers of your li

other solutions if you don't want to do that would be to have

```
<div id="{{'menuSidebar' + $index}}" ng-class="{active:someActive()}" class="panel-collapse collapse submenu-sidebar">
```

where "active:someActive" would be a function defined in your scope that traverses your submenu tree and returns true or false when some options are active.

bottom line it deppends on your layout and whether you prefer notifications or dirty check

Comment: if this is correct please mark it as the right answer so this can be closed ;) and yes so i can get the points

Answer (score 0):

I would create a scope function that takes in the link in question:

```
$scope.hasActiveChildren = function(link) {
    for(var i=0; i < link.sub.length; i++) {
        if(link.sub[i].active) {
            return true;   
        }
    }

    return false;
};
```

And then add it to the markup as you had above:

```
<div id="{{'menuSidebar' + $index}}" ng-class="{'active': hasActiveChildren(m)}" class="panel-collapse collapse submenu-sidebar">
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VSph2/196/)